# Maintaining session in an Eventlet page scraper?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, screen-scraping

I'm trying to do some scraping of a site that requires authentication (not http auth). The script I'm using is based on [this eventlet example](http://www.eventlet.net/doc/examples.html#web-crawler). Basically,

```
urls = ["https://mysecuresite.com/data.aspx?itemid=blah1",
     "https://mysecuresite.com/data.aspx?itemid=blah2",
     "https://mysecuresite.com/data.aspx?itemid=blah3"]

import eventlet
from eventlet.green import urllib2  

def fetch(url):
  print "opening", url
  body = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
  print "done with", url
  return url, body

pool = eventlet.GreenPool(10)
for url, body in pool.imap(fetch, urls):
  print "got body from", url, "of length", len(body)
```

Establishing the session is not simple at all; I have to load the login page, extract some variables from the login form, then send a POST request with the auth details and those variables. After the session is good, the rest of the requests are simple GET requests.

Using the above code as a reference point, how would I create a session that the rest of the pool would use? (I need the subsequent requests to be made in parallel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert on this by any means, but it looks like the standard way to maintain session state with urllib2 is to create a custom opener instance for each session.  That looks like this:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor())
```

Then you use that opener to do whatever authentication you have to, and all the session state will remain within the opener object itself.  Then you can pass the opener object as an argument for the parallel requests.

Here is an example script that logs in to secondlife.com for multiple users in parallel, and makes multiple page requests for each user, also in parallel.  The login procedure for this particular site is tricky because it involves capturing a CSRF token from the first request before being able to log in with the second.  For that reason, the login method is quite messy.  The principle should be the same, though, for whatever site you're interested in.

```
import eventlet
from eventlet.green import urllib2
import re

login_url = 'https://secure-web28.secondlife.com/my/account/login.php?lang=en&type=second-life-member&nextpage=/my/index.php?lang=en'

pool = eventlet.GreenPool(10)

def fetch_title(opener, url):
    match = re.search(r'<title>(.*)</title>', opener.open(url).read())
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
    else:
        return "no title"

def login(login_url, fullname, password):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor())
    login_page = opener.open(login_url).read()
    csrf_token = re.search(r'<input type="hidden" name="CSRFToken" value="(.*)"/>', login_page).group(1)
    username, lastname = fullname.split()
    auth = "CSRFToken=%s&form[type]=second-life-member&form[nextpage]=/my/index.php?lang=en&form[persistent]=Y&form[form_action]=Log%%20In&form[form_lang]=en&form[username]=%s&form[lastname]=%s&form[password]=%s&submit=Submit" % (
        csrf_token, username, lastname, password)
    logged_in = opener.open(login_url, auth).read()
    return opener


def login_and_fetch(login_url, fullname, password, page_urls):
    opener = login(login_url, fullname, password)
    # note that this deliberately uses the global pool
    pile = eventlet.GreenPile(pool)
    for url in page_urls:
        pile.spawn(fetch_title, opener, url)

    return pile

login_urls = [login_url] *2
usernames = [...]
passwords = [...]
page_urls = [['https://secure-web28.secondlife.com/my/account/?lang=en-US',
        'https://secure-web28.secondlife.com/my/community/events/index.php?lang=en-US']] * 2

for user_iter in pool.imap(login_and_fetch, login_urls, usernames, passwords, page_urls):
    for title in user_iter:
        print "got title", title
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, down to the tricky login bit. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Welcome!  Feel free to drop by the IRC channel #eventlet on freenode if you'd like to hang out with other Eventlet users and developers.

Answer (score 1):

Like suggested below, use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). It'll take care of the low-level details, like cookie management for you.

However, to make a 3rd party library work with eventlet you need to replace socket and ssl objects from stdlib with something that is asynchronous under the hood.

This is doable in eventlet, but it's not very straightforward here. 
I recommend using [gevent](http://www.gevent.org), where all you have to do is

> from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()

and then 3rd party libraries should just work.

Here's an [example](http://bitbucket.org/denis/gevent/src/tip/examples/concurrent_download.py).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `mechanize` library](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to make the session establishing easier, then use one of the different threading/multiprocessing techniques like this [threading pool recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/203871/) (first hit on Google, probably a bit overkill, make sure you read the comments).